# "direct" quotations and "entire paragraph" quotations

Tags: citing, quoting

I need two types of citations which I have not figured out how to define:

(see highlighted in grey)

> 1) As Owens stated (2008, p.97), `‘the value of...’`
>
> 2) Simone de Beauvoir (1972, p.365) examined her own past and wrote
>   rather gloomily:
>
> ```
> The past is not a peaceful landscape lying there behind me, a country in which I
> can stroll wherever I please, and will gradually show me all its secret hills and
> dates. As I was moving forward, so it was crumbling.
> ```

I am confused about how to use `\begin{quotation}` or similar machineries (`quote`|`quotation`|`verse`|etc.) to define quotes/quotations, etc.

I use `natbib` (this might be irrelevant).

I would normally define a quote as `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` but I find the lack of *association* between the quoted text and the actual bibliographic reference strange.

I don't know how to format a simple, in-text, quotation other than `blah' for single smart quotes and ``blah'' for double smart quotes.

Again, the fact that I am putting a "quote object" inside some flowing text and I am not associating it, even in a hidden way, with the bibliography database sounds strange to me.

I would find this more natural: `\shortquote[BibTeX:Reference][singlesmart]{Aha!}`, or something to that effect.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with `natbib` or bibliographic citations in general?

Comment: If it doesn't, please feel free to edit my question. I imagined natbib would have something like \citeliteralquote[fromword][toword]{bibtexreferenceid} to extract the quotation for me or something... it does not matter if my intution is wrong. All I need is a way to do 1) and 2), please

Comment: You seem to be asking `natbib` and BibTeX to do something for which they're neither designed nor particularly well suited. (Where would the quotes to be extracted reside, anyway? In some .bib file? If so, which field would one choose?) Just choose whatever quotation method (inline quote or block quote -- the latter via either the `quote` or the `quotation` environment) that best suits the circumstances.

Comment: Please post as answer, I will accept it. If you can, please add a tip on how I would define 'inline quotes'. Any Particular LaTeX command?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package and its various quoting commands?

Comment: No, I wasn't... (and how could you embed that link? cool!)

Comment: @Robottinosino to learn how to embed links into comments and how to get even more formatting, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Awesome comment. Upvoted. I'll keep the link in my bookmarks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your question is really about how to quote material -- either inline, with other text, or as a block quote. The fact that the material to be quoted comes from a specific cited source is peripheral to the issue, I believe.

- To quote a fairly short string -- whether a single word, a few words, or an entire sentence -- inline, you just surround it by the quotation marks that are appropriate for the language and region you're writing for. For example, in US English it's common to surround inline-quoted material with double back-quotes and double (forward) quotes, as in

  ```
    she said, ``Hello.''
  ```

  In UK English, it's more common to use single (back and forward) quotes. In other languages, other quotation mark styles prevail.

  - If there's a chance that your document will get translated in several languages, you may wish to familiarize yourself with the [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/) package and its `\enquote` command: Depending on the language specified as an option when this package is loaded, the language-specific (and, if applicable, region-specific) inline quotation sytle will be set up for you automatically.
- To typeset longer quoted material, especially if it's longer than a sentence, it's common to use either the `quote` or `quotation` environment. The latter is recommended if you're block-quoting more than one paragraph.

  - I should add that the styles of these two environments satisfy US-English typographic conventions but may not be perfect for other typographic systems. Again, the `csquotes` package can be of service, as it provides the `\blockquote` command to implement a block-quotation style that's tailored towards your language.

Comment: That's right, in Italian we sometimes need `<<` `>>` where you'd use `blah' or ``blah''.

Comment: How could one achieve a look like using `<Some Text>` in MarkDown (And in this site)? I mean the gray background when using '`' in MD.

Comment: @Royi - I'm afraid I don't understand your query. Would you mind elaborating on what it is you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: When you wrap text in MarkDown (Or any StackExchange Text Box) with '`<Text In Here>`' you get this gray background and Monospace Font. How could one get it in LaTeX?

Comment: @Royi  - I suppose one could load the `xcolor` package, define a macro such as `\newcommand\graybox[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\ttfamily #1}}`, and write `\graybox{<Text In Here>}` in the body of the document...

Comment: @Mico, You're great! I did this `\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1]{\colorbox{lightgray}{\texttt{#1}}}` after adding the package `xcolor` and now it is perfect. Thank You.

Answer (score 94):

Here is an example using the [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package.
It defines some new powerful commands for quoting, 
most notably the commands `\enquote`, `\textquote`, `\blockquote` and `\foreignquote`.

`\foreignquote` together with babel allows to define foreign quotes. The correct punctuation will automatically be used.

`\textquote` and `\blockquote` allow a citation as optional input, but from your example I guess the following is more what you want.

[image: Screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{owens2008,
    author = {Owens},
    title   = "Essay about Value",
    year    = "2008",
    journal = "International Journal of Interesting Stuff",
    volume  = "123",
    number  = "2",
    pages   = "205--319"}
@article{beauvoir1972,
    author  = "Beauvoir, Simone de",
    title   = "About the Gloomieness of landscape",
    year    = "1972",
    journal = "International Journal of Alphabetics",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "34--359"}
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage[round, sort, compress, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}  
%
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
As \citet[][p.97]{owens2008} stated, \enquote{the value of...}.
Some more lorem ipsum.\\
Some more lorem ipsum.
\citet[][p.365]{beauvoir1972} examined her own past and wrote rather gloomily:
\blockquote{The past is not a peaceful landscape lying there behind me, 
a country in which I can stroll wherever I please, 
and will gradually show me all its secret hills and dates. 
As I was moving forward, so it was crumbling. 
Some more text to make it longer than three lines. 
Maybe it is long enough now.}
Some more lorem ipsum.
Also there is an Italian proverb saying 
\foreignquote{italian}{Chi beve bene dorme bene,chi dorme bene sogna bene}. 
%
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```