# Keep block quotes text on single lines

Tags: line-breaking

I am using `CSQUOTES` package as suggested by [this TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/direct-quotations-and-entire-paragraph-quotations) question. It plays nicely with the nested `{}`s

How do I get the following (bibtex) text that has each line as a single line to remain on a single line, while in a blockquote (indented) format?  It should look like this, but in a blockquote:

```
@inproceedings{Velloso:2013:MMM:2470654.2466171,
 author = {Velloso, Eduardo and Bulling, Andreas and Gellersen, Hans},
 title = {MotionMA: Motion Modelling and Analysis by Demonstration},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
 series = {CHI '13},
 year = {2013},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1899-0},
 doi = {10.1145/2470654.2466171},
 acmid = {2466171},
 publisher = {ACM},
 ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. The problem is inside your .bib source file or when you insert the references with `\printbibliography`?

Comment: @Aradnix , no.   I a merely trying to have the above text each on its own line, in a block text format

Comment: Currently, it is in blockquotes, but not on an independent line

Comment: Why use a quote, and not some verbatim environment or other (`verbatim` or `lstlisting` from `listings`)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Provide some examples please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lstlisting` environment from the `listings` package to do this. It is a verbatim environment, meaning that everything in it is printed exactly as written, including whitespace, braces, backslashes etc. You can configure it to allow for wrapping of long lines (`breaklines=true`), and set an indentation with `xleftmargin=<length>`.

This way you don't have add all the line breaks manually, and escape all the braces. On the other hand, words will not be hyphenated automatically, as they are in your quote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % for comparison

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true,
        breakatwhitespace=false,
        columns=flexible,
        xleftmargin=2em}
\begin{document}

\noindent With \texttt{lstlistings}:
\begin{lstlisting}
@inproceedings{Velloso:2013:MMM:2470654.2466171,
 author = {Velloso, Eduardo and Bulling, Andreas and Gellersen, Hans},
 title = {MotionMA: Motion Modelling and Analysis by Demonstration},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
 series = {CHI '13},
 year = {2013},
 isbn = {978-1-4503-1899-0},
 doi = {10.1145/2470654.2466171},
 acmid = {2466171},
 publisher = {ACM},
 ...
}
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent With \texttt{blockquote}: 
\blockquote{
  @inproceedings\{Velloso:2013:MMM:2470654.2466171,\\*   
   author = \{Velloso, Eduardo and Bulling, Andreas and Gellersen, Hans\},\\*    
   title = \{MotionMA: Motion Modelling and Analysis by Demonstration\},\\*    
   booktitle = \{Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems\},\\*    
   year = \{2013\},\\* 
   isbn = \{978-1-4503-1899-0\},\\* 
   pages = \{1309--1318\},\\* 
   numpages = \{10\},\\* 
   url = \{http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2470654.2466171\},\\* 
   doi = \{10.1145/2470654.2466171\},\\* 
   acmid = \{2466171\},\\* 
   publisher = \{ACM\},\\* 
   address = \{New York, NY, USA\},\\* 
  \} \\* 
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the new line `\\*`

```
\blockquote{
  @inproceedings\{Velloso:2013:MMM:2470654.2466171,\\*   
   author = \{Velloso, Eduardo and Bulling, Andreas and Gellersen, Hans\},\\*    
   title = \{MotionMA: Motion Modelling and Analysis by Demonstration\},\\*    
   booktitle = \{Proceedings of the SIGCHI Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems\},\\*    
   year = \{2013\},\\* 
   isbn = \{978-1-4503-1899-0\},\\* 
   pages = \{1309--1318\},\\* 
   numpages = \{10\},\\* 
   url = \{http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2470654.2466171\},\\* 
   doi = \{10.1145/2470654.2466171\},\\* 
   acmid = \{2466171\},\\* 
   publisher = \{ACM\},\\* 
   address = \{New York, NY, USA\},\\* 
  \} \\* 
}
```