# Correct way to cite the page number (only) at the end of the citation

Tags: citing, natbib

[It seems it is NOT correct to include the page number before the citation](http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/res5e_ch09_s1-0001.html):

> According to Ferris [2007, p. 166-167]: "To get an accurate indicator
>   of commercial viability, don't ask people if they would buy—ask them
>   to buy"

(Code: `\cite[p.~166-167]{Ferris2007}`)

[It seems we must include the page number at the end of the citation](http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/res5e_ch09_s1-0001.html):

> According to Ferris [2007]: "To get an accurate indicator
>   of commercial viability, don't ask people if they would buy—ask them
>   to buy" [p. 166-167].

How could I do it? I'm using:

```
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

---

Note: It is correct to use the same code to add that reference at the end:

> (...) ask them to buy" [2007, p. 166-167]

Comment: The `2007` also belongs at the end. Just write your citation after the quotation. Sorry. I guess I'm not seeing what you're after here.

Comment: @cfr, I haven't found an example where the year is separated from the author. Check this post: http://bcs.bedfordstmartins.com/resdoc5e/res5e_ch09_s1-0001.html

Comment: Just add `~(p.~166--167)` after the quotation.

Comment: Yeah, it could work as a workaround. In my case I guess I should use brackets[] instead parentheses () as the formatting is like that. So: `As \cite{Ferris2007} said: "blablabla" ~[p.~166--167]`. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Just use `\citeauthor{Ferris2007}... \autocite*[166--167]{Ferris2007}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use  `biblatex` (which has a `natbib` emulation) you can define a `\citepages{key}` command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\citepages}[1]{\citefield{#1}[pagination]{pages}`
```

Result with one of my files:[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you have forgotten to add the code right? I mean, maybe the following is correct? `\citepages[p.~166-167]{Ferris2007}`

Comment: On the other hand, somebody wrote the page at the beginning here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/direct-quotations-and-entire-paragraph-quotations So maybe it is correct too??

Comment: I thought only of manually inserting page numbers at the end, as (I suppose) the quotation is *not* part of the .bib item.

Comment: Both are correct, in my opinion. Semantically, I think one can put page numbers *after* the quotation when one has several citations from different parts of a book, for instance, i.e. when the page range is not intrinsically attached to the reference.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to use the command `\citepages`

Comment: It supposes your .bib entry has a `pages` field. When you type `\citespages{entry key}`, it reads this field and prints `p. no`(or `pp. page range`), that's all. My example is an `inbook` entry, with this field: `pages = {734-752},`.

Comment: OK, but I cite the same book and different pages, so I think this solution is not for my case :/