# Recommendation for good quoting/citation technique?

Tags: biblatex, citing, quotation

It seems to me that there are several ways of quoting. I know of these:

- `package csquotes`: commands like `\enquote`
- `package BibLaTeX`: commands like `\autocite`, `\autocite` and `\textcite`
- `package quoting`
- `package cite`
- general(?) commands like `\cite`, `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}`

Is there an advice what package(s) to use? Is something more modern or even deprecated? Is there something like a "**good quoting technique**"?

I am using `BibLaTeX` and `Biber`, the desired language is **German**. Mainly I have the following cases:

1. direct quote of a sentence, inline ("... ." [AUT19, S.1])
2. direct quote of a paragraph, with an indent ("... ." [AUT19, S.1])
3. indirect quote of a sentence (... [AUT19].)
4. indirect quote of a paragraph (... . [AUT19])

Also: Is there a citation command that can distinguish between the cases of a citation of a sentence and of a paragraph and automatically places itself before or after the period? Or do I have to place the period by hand?

Comment: quoting convention often depend on the language/country

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will add this to my question :-)

Comment: Can you please add an short tex code showing what you do to get your 4 quotes? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing. I'm germany, you can use german text. At last it depends on your situation: is that an academic work you are doing? technical orientation or other? Which? Have you considered to ask that on graphicsdesign.SE (theme typography) or academia.SE? Only a small part of your question belongs to LaTeX at last ...  And it is personal opinion (what does "good quoting technique" means? What is "more modern"?) ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will keep them in mind for my next question (now that there already is a good answer)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting and citing are two different things and the commands used for the two jobs are mostly independent.

## Citing

I wrote about the 'evolution' of `\cite` and related commands in [A design question: citation commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473471/35864). Roughly speaking you could say that originally LaTeX only had `\cite` and that new commands were added to new packages as people realised that other citation commands would be useful and found a way to implement them.

Nowadays you probably have a choice between vanilla LaTeX's `\cite`, `cite`, `natbib` and `biblatex` (there are other specialised packages such as `apacite`, `jurabib`, ...). As a general rule you can only load one of the three packages `cite`, `natbib` and `biblatex` in your document. Each package has its advantages and disadvantages and there are many comparisons on this site that you could consult for your decision. [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864)

If you are using `biblatex` I suggest you try and use `\autocite` as your go-to citation command. `\autocite` is intended to be flexible and allow for easy changes of your citation style.

Very related: [Universal `\cite` commands or defining new cite commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158480/35864).

## Quoting

Standard LaTeX defines the `quote` and `quotation` environments for longer (indented) block quotes of text. The [`quoting`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) defines the environment `quoting` that is slightly more flexible than the standard LaTeX environments.

Then there is `csquotes` (by the same author as `biblatex`), which defines commands for short citations of a few words, longer block-quote citations and even has commands that allow you to combine quoting and citing into one (`\textcquote`, `\blockcquote`, ...). Have a look at [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) for all commands `csquotes` defines (I will show some important commands below).

Very related: ["direct" quotations and "entire paragraph" quotations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64371/35864).

## Example

`biblatex`'s `\autocite` and some `csquotes` commands have limited ability to move around punctuation marks. In almost all cases this can only happen if the punctuation mark comes *after* the command in question. But there is no command that knows if your citation is relevant only for a sentence or the entire paragraph. So in the end you have to decide where the punctuation should go.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite} % tell csquotes to use biblatex's \autocite for citations

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

Lorem ipsum \enquote{dolor} sit amet.

Lorem ipsum \textcquote[380]{sigfridsson}{dolor} sit amet.

\blockquote{\kant[1-2]}

Lorem ipsum dolor

\blockcquote[18]{kant:kpv}{\kant*[1]\par\kant*[2]}

\blockquote{Lorem ipsum dolor}

\blockcquote[18]{kant:kpv}{Lorem ipsum dolor}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: Thank you very much, that gave me a very good starting point!